# Combine two preg match to get viemo id and youtube id from url

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a client that may embed vimeo video or youtube video.
so i want to write a regex that get the id from url .

here's what i did :

```
 $y = '%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i';
 $v = '(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(player\.)?vimeo\.com\/([a-z]*\/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*';
 preg_match(($y) | ($v), $markup, $match);
 $markup = preg_replace('#\<iframe(.*?)\ssrc\=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)\>#i', '<iframe$1 src="$2&loop=1&amp;playlist='.$match[1].'"$3>', $markup);
```

but it gives me an error :

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '|' in
```

any idea ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use `preg_match($rx1 || $rx2, $text)` you should use a single regex with `|`. BTW, you do not need `preg_match` if you want to `preg_replace`.

Comment: can you please help me to write it ?

Comment: Right now, it is impossible, you did not show the sample data, nor expected outputs. Try yourself, then share the code if it still fails for you.

Comment: the condition is : grab the url and extract the id from url.
the data could be `https://vimeo.com/341989332` or `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUMbH6X_Adc` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/H7HMA

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for helping, it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't OR regex patterns like you do in `preg_match($rx1 || $rx2, $text)`, you should use a single regex with `|` separating alternatives. However, it might become too tricky here, as you need to capture a specific group. You might use either a [*branch reset group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) (`(?|...|...)` where alternatives retain grouping IDs) or [`\K` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) (that omits the text matched so far):

```
'~(?|(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})|vimeo\.com/(?:[a-z]+/)*([0-9]{6,11}))~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ixa8w/1). Or with `\K`:

```
'~(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)\K[^"&?/ ]{11}|vimeo\.com/(?:[a-z]+/)*\K[0-9]{6,11}~'
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ixa8w/2)

[PHP code](https://3v4l.org/H7HMA):

```
$rx = '~(?|(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})|vimeo\.com/(?:[a-z]+/)*([0-9]{6,11}))~';
$s = 'https://vimeo.com/341989332 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUMbH6X_Adc';
if (preg_match_all($rx, $s, $m)) {
    print_r($m[1]);
}
// => Array ( [0] => 341989332    [1] => eUMbH6X_Adc )
```